# How to compute the limit of the following product?

Tags: calculus

How to compute
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\frac{2}{n}...\frac{n}{n} $$ ?

Thanks,

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1959929/show-that-limsup-fracnnn-0/1959947

Answer (score 1):

Let

$$a_n = \frac{1}{n}\frac{2}{n}...\frac{n}{n}$$

Note that

$$a_n \leq \frac{1}{n}$$

Does this help?